# How to Stop referral Traffic in Google Analytics through Custom Filter

Tags: google-analytics

I was trying to add custom filter in Google Analytics to stop spam traffic using regular expressions. But not sure for below domains, which regular expression I need to use.

1. abc.xyz
2. reddit.com/r/technology
3. addons.mozilla.org
4. boltalko.xyz

Please help

Answer (score 2):

for mine, I select a Custom filter, select referrer, and then I just use the main domain bit like

```
abc\.xyz|reddit|addons\.mozilla\.org|boltalko
```

But if you need to use a .com bit, then make sure to escape it with a backslash

Comment: Thanks for help James. Much appreciated. Is it need to put space in between domain name and before using or expression like abc\.xyz| or abc \ . xyz |

Comment: I don't think a space is required for that. I don't use spaces in mine.